# Values aren't Grouping from Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression that evaluates the value enter to determine the blocks within the text. I have grouped the blocks. This Regular Expression will evaluate the Account ID entered in Various pattern.

> The AccountID is composed in the following way: [Prefix] + [Account
> Number] + [Account Type] + [Joint Account Number]
>
> - [Prefix] = [A-Za-z]  but not mandatory
> - [Account Number] = All numbers \d; Can range from 2-9 in length; Mandatory
> - [Account Type] = [A-Za-z];can be 1-2 length but not mandatory
> - [Joint Number] = \d; can be 1-2 in length but not mandatory

My Reg Ex:

```
(?<prefix>JKB)*\w*\s*(?<number>\d+)*\w*\s*(?<suffix>\W*)*\w*\s*(?<joint>\d*)
```

So I compiled some values for A/c JKB999LI00 in how users can write it:

9999LI
JKB9999LI00
JKB/999-LI/0
9999 LI
JKB 999 LI 00
9999LI 0
9999LI1
JKB000009999LI01
JKB-999-LI-00

I noticed that not all are placing in the group. What am I doing wrong here?

[My Working](https://regex101.com/r/YHzAu6/1)

NB: Sorry I am unable to share my work done from http://regexstorm.net/ as I couldn't find a share button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
^(?:(?<prefix>[A-Z]+)[\s/-]*)?(?<number>\d{2,9})(?:[\s/-]*(?<suffix>[A-Za-z]+))?(?:[\s/-]*(?<joint>\d{1,2}))?$
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cprefix%3e%5bA-Z%5d%2b%29%5b%5cs%2f-%5d*%29%3f%28%3f%3cnumber%3e%5cd%7b2%2c9%7d%29%28%3f%3a%5b%5cs%2f-%5d*%28%3f%3csuffix%3e%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b%29%29%3f%28%3f%3a%5b%5cs%2f-%5d*%28%3f%3cjoint%3e%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%29%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=9999LI%0d%0aJKB9999LI00%0d%0aJKB%2f999-LI%2f0%0d%0a9999+LI%0d%0aJKB+999+LI+00%0d%0a9999LI+0%0d%0a9999LI1%0d%0aJKB000009999LI01%0d%0aJKB-999-LI-00&o=m) and the [PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YHzAu6/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?<prefix>[A-Z]+)[\s/-]*)?` - an optional sequence of one or more capital letters (captured into Group "prefix") and then zero or more whitespaces, `/` or `-`
- `(?<number>\d{2,9})` - Group "number": two to nine digits
- `(?:[\s/-]*(?<suffix>[A-Za-z]+))?` - an optional sequence matching zero or more whitespaces, `/` or `-` and then Group "suffix" capturing one or more letters
- `(?:[\s/-]*(?<joint>\d{1,2}))?` - an optional sequence matching zero or more whitespaces, `/` or `-` and then Group "joint" capturing one or two digits
- `$` - end of string.